# Graphics display window remains hidden

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

NOTE: I have seen the problem described here only in OS X (Lion).

Matplotlib is a python library for data visualization.  When I attempt to display a graph on the screen, the window displaying the graph remains stubbornly hidden behind other windows.  The only way to see is by hiding, minimizing, or moving out of the way, all the other windows.  This makes interactive work with matplotlib unnecessarily cumbersome.

FWIW, one way to produce these results is shown below; all the steps shown (including the call to ipython) are taken from a matplotlib tutorial:

```
% ipython --pylab
...
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1, 3, 2, 4])
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x106aabd90>]
```

At this point, if there are no other windows to hide it (which is not usual), one sees that the window with the graph appears, but it does not get the focus.  Even after one clicks on it, it has the appearance of a window without the focus (e.g. the three buttons on the upper left corner remain light gray, instead of turning the usual red-yellow-green).

ALso, FWIW, I've observed *exactly the same behavior* with multiple styles of installation (on the same machine) of python+numpy+matplotlib+ipython, including installs that use the system-supplied python, those that use the python installed by `homebrew`, or those that use a python installed directly from source into a location off my home directory.

In case it matters, I have installed the ActiveTcl replacement for [the buggy Tcl and Tk frameworks that comes with Lion](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk).

(In contrast, when I run the above in Ubuntu, the figure window appears, with the focus, and on top of all other windows, as it should.)

Any ideas of what may be going on, or what I could do about it?

NOTE: I'm aware of Enthought's EPD, but this is not an option, for reasons too elaborate for me to go into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a general issue with Tkinter-based applications using Aqua Tk on OS X.  See [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue11571) for a discussion, what an app can do to work around it, and a proposed general solution.

Comment: Alas, like many open-source projects, Python development is done by volunteers and, due to the volume of issues, not all get addressed promptly.  A ping on the issue wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In that page you mention a patch to deal with the problem. That thread is over 2 years old, so I'm surprised that that patch has not made it to the latest version of Python (which is what I installed)... It looks like I need to figure out how to patch my Python source...